# A Borel set $E$ is a null set for the Borel measure that is induced by $\sigma(x)=x^2$ if and only if $E$ is a Lebesgue null set

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

> **Ture or False?** If $\sigma(x)=x^2$ on an interval $[a,b]$ and if $\sigma^*$ is the Borel measure on $[a,b]$ that is induced by $\sigma$, then a Borel set $E$ in $[a,b]$ is a null set for $\sigma^*$ if and only if $E$ is a Lebesgue null set.

Well, I don't quite get what $\sigma^*$ really does. If $A\subseteq [a,b]$ then how does one define $\sigma^*(A)$? Would it be $b^2-a^2$? I guess I need some explanation on the word "induced". Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You need $a\geq 0$ for this question to make sense right?

Comment: @Shashi Given KaviRamaMurthy's definition on $\sigma^*$, I don't see a problem for $a$ being negative, though.

Answer (score 1):

Definition of $\sigma^{*}$: $\sigma^{*}(A)=m \{x: x^{2} \in A\}$ where $m$ is Lebesgue measure. The fact that $ m(A)=0$ iff $\sigma^{*} (A)=0$ is a consequence of the following theorem: if $f$ is absolutely continuous then $f$ maps sets of measure $0$ to sets of measure $0$. The function $f(x)=x^{2}$ is absolutely continuous because it is the indefinite integral of $x \to 2x$. Simialrly, use the fact that the function $\sqrt {|x|}$ is integrable for the converse part.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I don't quite get your last line. Did you mean take $f(x)=2x$? So take $A\subseteq [a,b]$ then $m(A)=0\implies \int_A 2xdm=0\implies \int_A d\sigma^*=0$. Is this what you were suggesting?

Comment: @Alex I have edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks for updating. Now we have $m(A) = 0 \implies m(f(A))=0 $ since $f(x)=x^2$ is abs. continuous. Then $m\{x|x^2\in A\}=0\implies \sigma^*(A)=0$, which looks good. For the opposite direction, I still don't get how $\sqrt{|x|}$ works. But $\sigma^*(A)=0\implies \int_Ad\sigma^* = 0\implies \int_A 2xdx = 0\implies m(A)=0$. Does this make sense?

Comment: @Alex When $a\geq 0$, we have $\sqrt x =\sqrt a +\frac 1 2 \int_a^{x} \frac 1 {\sqrt t}\, dt$ so $\sqrt x$ is absolutely continuous. I leave it to you to consider the case $a<0$.